# SSIS Derived Column how to format my month display?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a column named [Month] which has the months as such..

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

What I want to be able to do is for the first 1-9 is add a 0 so that they read...

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

How would I do this via a derived column? (running SQL Server 2012)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

after add derived column in expression write this code

RIGHT("00"+(DT_WSTR,2)Month,2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 15, 100
```

Derived column code:

```
Month < 10 ? "0" + (DT_WSTR,3)Month : (DT_WSTR,3)Month
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try: `select right ('00'+ltrim(str([Month])),2 )`

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    case 
       when [Month] < 10 then '0' 
                         else '' 
    end + ltrim(rtrim(cast([Month] as varchar)))
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!